# How does one define a model association in Sails.js that requires additional criteria and/or data from a third model/table?

Tags: model, sails.js, associations

I'm working on an app and having some difficulty with model associations in Sails.js. I've started with the generic web app. The app is to track outdoor education classes. I currently only have one User model, but users may potentially have multiple "roles." The same user, for example, may be both a course instructor or a student.

I have models for User, Role, class Section, and School. The association between User and Role is straightforward and works. The same for Section and School (a class Section "belongs" to a School). However, I'd like to define an association on Section to list students that belong to that section. Doing so would require returning users whose role(s) include "student" or storing the record ID of the User<->Role('student') table/relationship.

Does Sails support a "has many through" where you can filter the intermediate join table?

...or is there another way to solve this? I've tried talking to a rubber ducky with no luck, but I feel like there's another solution staring me in the face.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a many-to-many relationship and then filter with **Module.populate()** as the documentation shows:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate

Or event the through associations:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations